# Getting error on every application I create for Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Whenever I create a new application in Visual Studio for Windows Phone 7, every time I build my application this error pops up:

> The application could not be launched
>   for debugging. Ensure that the target
>   device screen is unlocked and that
>   application is installed.

Due to this error my application is not running in the emulator. I tried reinstalling the SDK and Visual Studio but can't seem to solve this error.

Comment: Are you sure that you're launching the emulator and not trying to launch the app on an actual device?

Comment: i am not sure. Can you guide me how to check that ?

Comment: @Pro_Zeck - There should be a toolbar with a dropdown that has two options. The first is Windows Phone Emulator and the second is Windows Phone Device. Make sure the emulator is selected before you start debugging.

Comment: @Justin- Its already Window Phone Emulator.still its giving me that error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say a 'new application', do you mean a completley new application, or have you added some code? I've heard this error occurring if you try and add non WP7 project to your WP7 solution. Right-click on your solution and select `Properties`. Open the `Configuration Properties` panel on the left and make sure that `Build` and `Deploy` are both selected. 
Also, make sure your project is the startup project (right click on your project and select `Set as Startup Project`.

Comment: thank you Deploy was uncheck due to which the error was coming :)

Comment: No idea why, but this problem occurred to me at some moment while busy. Hadn't changed the config manually, but it just did. Thanks for this solution mate, caused me a big headache...

Comment: @Hutjepower - No problem, glad it's still a useful answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Visual Studio toolbar should look like this (Having `Windows Phone 7 Emulator` in the target dropdown):

[image: Emulator Selected]

Comment: @Pro_Zeck does this happen for new WP7 projects or just this one? Does it only happen on Debug (F5) or also on run without debugging (Ctrl-F5)?

Comment: @TheChristKent This happens with all the WP7 projects. Even if i press (Ctrl-F5) its says application is not installed, when i press f5 my first error pops up .

Comment: @Pro_Zeck are you able to launch the emulator yourself?  Should be in your Start Menu: All Programs > Windows Phone Developer Tools > Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Comment: @TheChrist i just checked it out that when i open my project on which this error is coming its Target is set to Window Phone Device and when i reset it to Emulator this error pops up "The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that application is installed"

Comment: @Pro_Zeck but are you able to run the emulator on it's own? (not launched by visual studio), see instructions above.

Comment: @Prozeck yeah i am able to run it own my own